# Translating text with py_translate in python: ValueError: ('No JSON object could be decoded')

Tags: python, google-translate, valueerror, language-translation

I have a pandas dataframe that has a bunch of text that is in either English or French. I want to translate the French text into English. I am using a lambda like this:

```
from py_translator import Translator
import pandas as pd

translator = Translator()
// read data into dataframe df

df.apply(lambda x:pre_process(x, translator), axis=1)
```

The translation happens in the pre_process function:

```
def pre_process(data, translator):
    text = data['text']

    # Detect french or english: if French, translate to English
    language = detect(text)
    if(language == 'fr'):
        text = translator.translate(text, src='fr', dest='en')

    data['text'] = text
```

I run a test version with just a few french documents and everything seems to be fine. However, when I run the full version, I get an error before too long:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 120, in <module>
    df.apply(lambda x:pre_process(x, translator), axis=1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6014, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 142, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 248, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 277, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "tfidf_keyword_extraction_w_scikit.py", line 120, in <lambda>
    df.apply(lambda x:pre_process(x, translator), axis=1)
  File "tfidf_keyword_extraction_w_scikit.py", line 36, in pre_process
    text = translator.translate(str(text), src='fr', dest='en').text
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_translator/client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_translator/client.py", line 81, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_translator/utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py_translator/utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: ('No JSON object could be decoded', u'occurred at index 17')
```

I can't seem to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With minor changes to your code (`return`, `language.lang` and `translator.translate(text, src='fr', dest='en').`**text** , it worked.

```py
from py_translator import Translator
import pandas as pd

translator = Translator()

df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2],
                   'text': [u'«Il a neigé !» cria Jean tout excité lorsqu’il regarda par la fenêtre ce matin-là.',
                            u'Il était allé à la montagne avec ses amis Sophie, Charles et Félix pour les vacances d’hiver.'
                           ]})


def pre_process(data, translator):
    text = data['text']

    # Detect french or english: if French, translate to English
    language = translator.detect(text)
    if(language.lang == 'fr'):
        text = translator.translate(text, src='fr', dest='en').text

    return text

df['en'] = df.apply(lambda x:pre_process(x, translator), axis=1)
print (df)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! unfortunately it still gives me an error when I run it on the full dataset. The dataset has around 40000 elements so it's quite large, maybe that is causing problems?

Comment: I tried it now with many rows in the dataframe and reproduced your error. After that, I couldn't even run my two examples, and got also the error. Google Translate has blocked us for some time. If I give it a `service_url='translate.google.com'`, 
I get the error: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='t', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ...`
py_translate is just an interface to the web.

My proposal would be, to translate the dataset in parts over some time and save the results on your hard drive.

Comment: That makes sense. I am going to try breaking up the dataset into smaller parts and running it.

Comment: I tried running it in smaller chunks, it gives me the JSON error by the second one. I'm going to try spacing it out a bit more

Comment: When you find some working spacing for the chunks, let me know. Maybe you can also pack up 100 sentences with some delimiter and translate a bunch with one call.

Comment: I'm getting pretty confused. I tried splitting the data into chunks but I am still getting the JSON ValueError. I get this error on the very first chunk of text I'm trying to translate (I don't know why I said second earlier, sorry). The text is originally a unicode string, I tried converting to ascii but still get the same result.

Comment: Another thing I should probably mention: I am running this script on a server I'm accessing via ssh. I tried running your code above and another test case on my local machine and it works no problem

Comment: when I try running your code above on the server I get the same error. Is google translate blocking the server IP?

Comment: Ask google :) I think, if you got once a day blocked, you get the confusing json error. If you try to minimize the chunks each day for you are trying, may be you find the amount, that google accepts for the translation request. It worked also for me the first times and then nothing worked. Maybe there is a better way to download the google models for translating, but that seems also to be a secret.

Comment: isn't this problem caused by your requests reaching the API quotas? check if you translate more than 10000 characters per second. https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas